# What is the value of $a-b$ when $a$ and $b$ are constants

Tags: mixing-variables

The expression $x^2-k^2$ where $k$ is a constant is equivalent to the expression $(x+a)(x-b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. What is the value of $a-b$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Questions are typically better received if you include some of your working or attempts on the problem - it allows people here to help you more effectively.

Comment: Do you know how to factor a difference of squares?

Comment: For $(x+a)(x-b)=x^2+(a-b)x-ab$ to be equivalent to $x^2-k^2=x^2+0x-k^2$, their coefficients must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$x^2 -k^2 = x^2 + 0x - k^2$$

Can you take this from here? Also take note of fourRightRotation's hint.